# (Possibly bugs? ) Wrong results provided by `DEigensystem`

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, eigenvalues

I was trying `DEigensystem` with the following code:

```
DEigensystem[{-u''[x] + x u'[x], DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]},u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 2]
```

And after a period of time of calculation, it returns the following results:[image]

It surprised me that the first eigen value is a complex `Root` expression while the second one is a simple integer 10, however after a while I realized that the second solution was actually zero:[image]
So 10 should not be the eigen value of this operator. The plot of the following code shows that every even integer is the solution of `u[1]==0` with boundary condition `u[0]==0`

```
Plot[Log@RealAbs[DSolveValue[{-u''[x] + x u'[x] - \[Lambda] u[x] == 0, u[0] == 0}, u[x], x] /. {C[_] :> 1, x :> 1} // Evaluate], {\[Lambda], 0, 15}]
```

[image]

However, when `\[Lambda]` equals to even numbers, the general solution is actually zero, and the special solution is not zero at point `x==1`:

```
Limit[DSolveValue[{-u''[x] + x u'[x] - \[Lambda] u[x] == 0, u[0] == 0}, u[x], x] /. {C[_] :> 1}, \[Lambda] -> 10] // Simplify

(*0*)

DSolveValue[{-u''[x] + x u'[x] - \[Lambda] u[x] == 0, u[0] == 0} /. \[Lambda] -> 10, u[x], ] /. {C[_] :> 1} // Simplify

(*(-2 E^(x^2/2) x (2895 - 2640 x^2 + 588 x^4 - 44 x^6 + x^8) + 
 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (-945 + 4725 x^2 - 3150 x^4 + 630 x^6 - 45 x^8 + x^10) Erfi[x/Sqrt[2]])/7257600*)

% /. x -> 1

(*(-1600 Sqrt[E] + 1216 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Erfi[1/Sqrt[2]])/7257600*)
```

So my question is: How to get the right `DEigensystem` result of the operator above automatically? By the way, all of the codes give the same result in version 12.1, 12.2 and 12.3.

Comment: Please do not use the *bugs* tag for unconfirmed / potential bugs, per site convention. I have removed it pending confirmation.

+1, btw, for a nicely written question.

Comment: The same issue with `DEigensystem[{-u''[x] + x u'[x], DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]},
  u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 3]`: the second and third eigenfunctions are zero.